# Android 4.0 - 4.3 - How to set font-size for the figcaption element

Tags: android, css, mobile, fonts

i want to adapt the view of an existing web app for mobile applications.
I have to devices at hand:

1. Samsung Galaxy S III (Android 4.3) dpr: 2
2. Samsung Duos (Android 4.04) dpr 1.5

The background changes successfully in both using the respective media expression, but the font-size does not change for the figcaption element.

```
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0)
```

These expressions I just use for testing.
No matter if I use px,%, etc. the font-size is not applied to the figcaption element. But on the body it does increase the font-size.
I use a simple html page with css included.

CanIuse says: [figcaption](http://caniuse.com/#search=figcaption)
Does not include support for the main element, for Android 4.3.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) {
        /* CSS for low-density screens */
        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        figcaption {
            font-size:30px;
            font-size: 5rem; /*0.5vmin*/
        }

            figcaption h1 {
                font-size:35px;
                font-size: 5.6rem; /*0.6vmin*/
            }
    }
```